# Enabling HugePage support in CentOS

Tags: centos5, linux

I'm trying to tune JVM performance by adding +UseLargePages parameter. As it threw error, I figured that it's not supported in my OS. I'm using **CentOS (5.10) -- Linux 2.6.16.33-xenU 64** bit distribution. Here's what I get when I run the following java command.

```
java -Xmx400m -XX:+UseLargePages -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory (errno = 38).
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

**grep -i Huge /proc/meminfo** shows no information. This made it clear that the HugePages support in not available.
I installed **libhugetlbfs** , if now run **rpm -qi libhugetlbfs**, I get the following information.

`Name        : libhugetlbfs                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.3                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 8.2.el5                       Build Date: Thu Jan 20 20:36:26 2011
Install Date: Fri Mar  7 18:44:57 2014         Build Host: builder10.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: libhugetlbfs-1.3-8.2.el5.src.rpm
Size        : 111296                           License: LGPLv2+
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Mon Mar 21 19:35:33 2011, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
URL         : http://libhugetlbfs.sourceforge.net
Summary     : Library to access the Huge TLB Filesystem
Description :
The libhugetlbfs library interacts with the Linux hugetlbfs to make large pages
available to applications in a transparent manner.
Name        : libhugetlbfs                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.3                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 8.2.el5                       Build Date: Thu Jan 20 20:42:35 2011
Install Date: Fri Mar  7 18:44:57 2014         Build Host: builder10.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: libhugetlbfs-1.3-8.2.el5.src.rpm
Size        : 108116                           License: LGPLv2+
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Mon Mar  7 09:43:30 2011, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
URL         : http://libhugetlbfs.sourceforge.net
Summary     : Library to access the Huge TLB Filesystem
Description :
The libhugetlbfs library interacts with the Linux hugetlbfs to make large pages
available to applications in a transparent manner.`

Still no luck with HugePages support.

Just wondering if I'm missing something or this version of linux is doesn't support this feature at all.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't running a Red Hat kernel. That's probably why you aren't getting hugepages. Try installing `kernel-xen` and booting from that (e.g. with pvgrub).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your help. I'm not a linux expert, can you provide some information to install kernel -xen on CentOS 5? I did try some option by googling few articles, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Eh? How did you end up with this system, then?

Answer (score 1):

To check if your kernel supports HugePage use the following command. If you get the output like this your kernel supports HugePage.

```
[root@prashant sa]# grep HUGETLB /boot/config-$(uname -r)

CONFIG_HUGETLBFS=y

CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE=y
```

To install new kernel

```
yum install kernel
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try updating the kernel, but didn't make any difference. I ended up updating the OS to 6.2

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't fix your issue, but CentOS 5 is ancient and end of life since March 31st 2017 (i.e. no updates and no support of any kind anymore).

You should really migrate to CentOS 6 or 7 as soon as possible.